# Firebase/Firestore document not updating

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble with updating a document data with angular/firestore & Firebase.

The value i'm trying to update is successfully updating in the DOM but isn't saved in Firebase and so it resets to the original value on page reload.

I'm getting this error:

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() requires at least 2 arguments, but was called with 1 argument

In my service :

```
updateWord(word: Words, newState: string) {
  this.firestore.doc("words/" + word.word).update(word.state = newState);
}
```

In my component.ts :

```
changeState(word: Words, state: string) {
  this.wordsService.updateWord(word, state);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update method expects a `Partial<Words>` object, you are updating it with a string.

<sub>the value of `newState` is returned from the `word.state = newState` assignment</sub>

You should just pass an object which contains the new updates to your object:

```
updateWord(word: Words, newState: string) {
  this.firestore.doc<Words>(`words/`${word.word}).update({ state: newState });
}
```

Read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) for the appropriate API usage of firestore

<sub>Don't forget about error handling and/or returning of the promise from the update call so you can chain it and handle any error that might occur</sub>

Comment: Thanks, worked for this error ! It's now giving me a "no document to update", but it seems to know the document... "word.word" is giving me all the document informations.

Comment: @LLP what are the contents of `word.word`? You need to find the id of the word to update the right path, I thought you had that stored in `word.word`.

Comment: Id was the missing part ! It's perfectly working now. Id wasn't in my "Words" interface but generated by firebase, so i wasn't using it.